# Show comments only from that article

Tags: php, laravel

When I foreach all my comments I get all my comments but I want to see only the comments from that article... How can I do that in my foreach?

db: atricles

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('userID')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->integer('points');
        $table->integer('amountComments');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

db:comments

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('articleID')->unsigned();
        $table->string('comment');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

show comments from articles

```
<div class="comments"> 
        @if ($article->amountComments > 0)
            <ul>
                @foreach ($comments as $comment)
                    <li>
                        <div class="comment-body">{{ $comment->comment }}</div>
                        <div class="comment-info">Posted by {{ $article->username }} on {{ $comment->created_at }}
                            @if ($comment->user_id == Auth::id())
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit-btn"
                                href="{{ route('edit_comment', ['comment' => $comment->id]) }}">edit</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs edit-btn"
                                href="{{ route('delete_comment', ['comment' => $comment->id]) }}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash" title="delete"></i>delete
                                </a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        @else
            <div>   
                <p>No comments yet</p>
            </div>
        @endif                          

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code where you are getting the comments? Sounds like you just need a where clause adding. Our you can orm in the models top get the comments. Post your controller then we can edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get comments for this article. If you don't use Eloquent relationships, do this:

```
$comments = Comment::where('articleID', $article->id)->get();
```

Another way is to use eager loading. First, define a relationship:

```
public function comments()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'articleID');
}
```

Then load the data:

```
$article = Article::with('comments')->find($id);
```

And display the comments:

```
@foreach ($article->comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment->comment }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, forgot in my model the 'articleID'

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
@foreach ($article->comments as $comment)
```

And in your Article model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'articleID');
}
```

Laravel will do the rest for you.

Take a Look at the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

And it would be easier if you follow Laravel convention, using `article_id` instead of `articleID`.

Comment: I already had made the relation in my model but didnt do put 'articleID' with it, thank you!

Comment: You will see a "V" (check) mark on the top left of this answer, bellow the arrows and de "1" number.

Comment: @Felippe you could tell OP that you've originally posted relationship without custom foreign ID and added it after I've posted the correct code. Instead you're asking OP to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: You could tell that you've originally posted without Eloquent and then added it after I posted the correct code. I'm "asking" because he is new here and need to know how things works on SO. And I didn't saw your code to write my answer.

Comment: I've added an Eloquent solution in a minute after my original post, why is this important? It's usual practice at SO. I've posted the correct code, you've edited your answer in like 2 minutes after that and added the FK too. Adding FK solved the problem and now you're asking OP to mark your answer. Nice behavior. @Enzo, mark the guy's answer as the best please, it's seems it's really important for him.

Comment: I don't care, I just don't like when people tell me that I'm cheating or lying. The mark as accepted is to help OTHERS, not to increase reputation.